# How to access the content in an array?

Tags: python, ros

Hey Iam new to python I am trying to print the text message,which is located inside the array status_list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from actionlib_msgs.msg import GoalStatusArray

def callback(data):
    print(data.status_list)


def listener():

    # In ROS, nodes are uniquely named. If two nodes with the same
    # name are launched, the previous one is kicked off. The
    # anonymous=True flag means that rospy will choose a unique
    # name for our 'listener' node so that multiple listeners can
    # run simultaneously.
    rospy.init_node('listener', anonymous=True)

    rospy.Subscriber("/move_base/status", GoalStatusArray, callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    listener()
```

This is the output of the above code.

```
[goal_id: 
  stamp: 
    secs: 44
    nsecs:  46000000
  id: "/move_base-1-44.46000000"
status: 3
text: "Goal reached."]
```

How can I access the goal reached message?Thank you.

Comment: sorry i got it its,print(data.status_list[0].text)

Comment: Would be awesome if you just post this as an answer I suppose : https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to try from list index like:

```
list[0],[1]
```

From that, you will able to do that. It means you are taking the first index:

```
(data.status_list[0].text)
```